# Как сделать подсвеченным элемент при клике?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

при клике сработала подсветка всех элементов  с одинаковым id. срабатывает только первый.

```js
$(".chita").click(function() {
  $("#chita").toggleClass("shadow");
})
$(".krasnoy").click(function() {
  $("#krasnoy").toggleClass("shadow");
})
$(".omsk").click(function() {
  $("#omsk").toggleClass("shadow");
})
```

```css
.shadow {
  background: rgba(196, 196, 196, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#" class="*">Все</a>
  <a href="#" class="chita">Чита</a>
  <a href="#" class="krasnoy">Красноярск</a>
  <a href="#" class="omsk">Омск</a>
  <dt id="chita">
            <a href="#">
                <h5>Зав. производством</h5>
            </a>
        </dt>
  <dt id="krasnoy">
            <a href="#"><h5>Старший повар</h5></a>
        </dt>
  <dt id="omsk">
            <a href="#"><h5>Помощник повара</h5></a>
        </dt>
  <dt id="chita">
            <a href="#"><h5>Слесарь</h5></a>
        </dt>
  <dt id="krasnoy">
            <a href="#"><h5>Сантехник</h5></a>
        </dt>
  <dt id="omsk">
            <a href="#"><h5>Прачка</h5></a>
        </dt>
</div>
```

Comment: В чем смыл использовать тег без родного контейнера `<dl><dt></dt><dd></dd></dl>`?

Comment: Не может быть в документе неуникальных идентификаторов `id`. Для обозначения можете использовать атрибут `data-city`

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".chita").click(function() {
  $("#chita").toggleClass("shadow");
})
$(".krasnoy").click(function() {
  $("#krasnoy").toggleClass("shadow");
})
$(".omsk").click(function() {
  $("#omsk").toggleClass("shadow");
})

$(".vse").click(function() {
  $("dt").toggleClass("shadow");
})
```

```css
.shadow {
  background: rgba(196, 196, 196, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#" class="vse">Все</a>
  <a href="#" class="chita">Чита</a>
  <a href="#" class="krasnoy">Красноярск</a>
  <a href="#" class="omsk">Омск</a>
  <dt id="chita">
            <a href="#">
                <h5>Зав. производством</h5>
            </a>
        </dt>
  <dt id="krasnoy">
            <a href="#"><h5>Старший повар</h5></a>
        </dt>
  <dt id="omsk">
            <a href="#"><h5>Помощник повара</h5></a>
        </dt>
  <dt id="chita">
            <a href="#"><h5>Слесарь</h5></a>
        </dt>
  <dt id="krasnoy">
            <a href="#"><h5>Сантехник</h5></a>
        </dt>
  <dt id="omsk">
            <a href="#"><h5>Прачка</h5></a>
        </dt>
</div>
```

Comment: Да автор имел ввиду и то, что не подсвечиваются элементы кроме первого, например при клике на `Красноярск` должно быть `[Старший повар, Сантехник]`, но там и `id`-шки неуникальные

Comment: спасибо, что поясняете. не могу разобраться с как правильно с [-id ]  , может ссылку на материал по теме или сам код

Comment: [<dt data-city="chita">] изменил, как в скрипте прописать правильно  [$("chita").toggleClass("shadow");]

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, я там вообще не вижу ни  **ни уникальный ID** ни **уникальный ID**, о чем речь...?

Comment: @ssv64, вопрос надо задавать так, что бы было понятно, что именно хочет реализовать автор... Тут ясновидящих нет....

Comment: @Air "... не вижу ... "(c). Речь об идентификаторах(атрибутах) элементов `dt`, которые могут быть только уникальными. Например `id="omsk"` повторяется 2 раза.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите, вся проблема в том, что вы используете **id** чтобы выбрать нужные вам элементы. Всё бы ничего, если не была такая маленькая мелочь, как **уникальность атрибута id**.

Вот абзац из справочника:

> **id** задает стилевой идентификатор — уникальное имя элемента, которое
>   используется для изменения его стиля и обращения к нему через скрипты.
>   Идентификатор в коде документа должен быть в единственном экземпляре,
>   иными словами, **встречаться только один раз**.

Конкретно в вашем примере, я бы порекомедовал элементам dt задать другой атрибут, например class или data атрибут по желанию(хотя я всё же рекомендовал бы первый вариант).

```js
$(".chita").click(function() {
  $(".chita-example").toggleClass("shadow");
})
$(".krasnoy").click(function() {
  $(".krasnoy-example").toggleClass("shadow");
})
$(".omsk").click(function() {
  $(".omsk-example").toggleClass("shadow");
})
$(".vse").click(function() {
  $("dt").toggleClass("shadow");
})
```

```css
.shadow {
  background: rgba(196, 196, 196, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <a href="#" class="vse">Все</a>
    <a href="#" class="chita">Чита</a>
    <a href="#" class="krasnoy">Красноярск</a>
    <a href="#" class="omsk">Омск</a>

    <dl>
        <dt class="chita-example">
            <a href="#"><h5>Зав. производством</h5></a>
        </dt>
        <dt class="krasnoy-example">
            <a href="#"><h5>Старший повар</h5></a>
        </dt>
        <dt class="omsk-example">
            <a href="#"><h5>Помощник повара</h5></a>
        </dt>
        <dt class="chita-example">
            <a href="#"><h5>Слесарь</h5></a>
        </dt>
        <dt class="krasnoy-example">
            <a href="#"><h5>Сантехник</h5></a>
        </dt>
        <dt class="omsk-example">
            <a href="#"><h5>Прачка</h5></a>
        </dt>
    </dl>
</div>
```